# Declaring Array in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a global array in Typescript so that I can access it with "this" from anywhere. In javascript I would declare it like "`var anArray=[]`". How do I do exactly the same with Typescript.

`anArray:Array<any>` seems not working.

Comment: It's not about how you declare it, it's about where you declare it. `window.anArray: any[] = [];` should work fine from anywhere, but obviously global variables are not the way to go, in any language.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors from the compiler? Have you tried: 
var anArray: Array<any> = [];

Answer (score 1):

Try this format

```
let list: any[] = [5, true, "one"];
```

Refer : [Documentation Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)